# Collapsing columns in a table without jquery by click and by url

Tags: javascript, html

for our intranet i've to do a large table with lots of columns.
As there are many columns, i want to be able to hide some "blocks" of columns for better overview.

The columns have two headings, one as kind of grouping for the "Progress step" and one under it with details for each step.

I found several solutions but the problem is that it is required to hide each group/step by click, but it should be also possible to have predefined views like a short overview, detailed view, maybe reachable by a url?

Currently the table heading looks like:

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <colgroup>
                <col>
                  <col>
                  <col>
                  <col span='11' class='step0'>
                  <col span='2' class='step1'>
                  <col span='3' class='step2'>
                  <col span='3' class='step3'>
                  <col span='3' class='step4'>
</colgroup>
<tr>
                    <th rowspan='2'>ID</th>
                    <th rowspan='2'>Name</th>
                    <th rowspan='2'>State</th>
                    <th colspan='11'>Step 0</th>

                    <th colspan='2'>Step 1</th>

                    <th colspan='3'>Step 2</th>
                    <th colspan='3'>Step 3</th>
                    <th colspan='3'>Step 4</th>

</tr>
<tr>
                    <th>Step 0 - Info 1</th>
                    <th>Step 0 - Info 2</th>
                    <th>Step 0 - Info 3</th>
                    <th>Step 0 - Info 4</th>
                    <th>Step 0 - Info 5</th>
                    <th>Step 0 - Info 6</th>
                    <th>Step 0 - Info 7</th>
                    <th>Step 0 - Info 8</th>
                    <th>Step 0 - Info 9</th>
                    <th>Step 0 - User+Date</th>
                    <th>Step 0 - Notes</th>

                    <th>Step 1 - User+Date</th>
                    <th>Step 1 - Notes</th>

                    <th>Step 2 - Info</th>
                    <th>Step 2 - User+Date</th>
                    <th>Step 2 - Notes</th>

                    <th>Step 3 - Info</th>
                    <th>Step 3 - User+Date</a></th>
                    <th>Step 3 - Notes</th>

                    <th>Step 4 - Info</th>
                    <th>Step 4 - User+Date</th>
                    <th>Step 4 - Notes</th>
                  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

As i never used jquery (and can't even code JS besides a bit modification of existing scripts,
i'd prefer a solution without jquery. If it is much easier with jquery, i'd have a look.

Maybe one column of each group should stay visible, but that could be achieved by modifying the colgroup :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simple solution: You can have 2 tables and then display the simple one like the summary and if the user wants more data, he can click button to hide the summary and show the larger one

Comment: That's the way it's currently done but i'd prefer to be able to hide specific steps of the table via JS, i found several ways to hide columns but not to additionally define kind of views.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is kind of obsolete, if you don’t need to support quite old platforms. So you’re right in searching for a non-jQuery solution.

It’s not necessary to code JS yourself, as there are plenty of libraries out there that you can use for such purposes. Usually they come in so called packages, which can be installed by means of the [node package manager (npm)](https://www.npmjs.com/).

Learning how to integrate npm can be quite long, so you can also download libraries (aka scripts) that you might find on the web. It’s important that the download includes all dependencies.

You will need to ask yourself some questions, though, to be able to choose the right library/script:

- What is the UI pattern that you want to use? This will determine your search keyword

  - Collapse column-groups into one column? This is called a collapse pattern, I would recommend it due to it’s intuitiveness.
  - Have a checklist on your site to hide the step completely from the table?
- Should the solution be accessible to users with situational, temporary or permanent disabilities? Include the keyword accessible or a11y in your search

  - The minimum should be keyboard support
- What platforms need to be supported (browser version and operating system)?
- Is there already another JavaScript framework used in the intranet, like jQuery or other?

  - You would either like to look for a library that integrates well,
  - or one that uses “vanilla” JavaScript, so no framework at all
- Are you using a build system, into which the library should integrate? Ask the architects, if you don’t know
- How much of your solution would you be willing to replace by a library?

  - There are [Data Grid libraries](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-groups/) out there that offer your functionality, but will build the whole table based on JavaScript, instead of simply adding functionality
  - or would you like to apply *progressive enhancement*, meaning you’re simply adding functionality on top of a already fully usable table? (I’d recommend that)
- Which licenses do you accept? There are different open source licenses, that allow you manipulating code or not, and might oblige you to publish any changes you make

Finally, the library will need a mapping between the toggle and the columns to hide somewhere. It can be done in JavaScript only, but I would recommend to use a library that makes use of HTML attributes instead, so that you don’t need to write JavaScript.

If the library is specialised in tables, it might use the already present `colspan` attributes to do the mapping.

Otherwise, you might have to provide the mapping with `data-` attributes.

So, your search might be like “Accessible collapsible column groups javascript”.

#### Example with Bootstrap

Here is an example based on [Bootstrap’s Collapse Component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/#multiple-targets). Bootstrap is a framework and supports accessibility. Some particularities concerning accessibility in tables might be missing.

Note that you cannot hide cells directly, if you keep the grouping header visible, since the table’s structure would fall apart.

If you go for the checklist solution instead of a collapse pattern, you could use the same component, and reference all cells (including those with colspan) in the `data-bs-target` attribute.

```html
…
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Step 0 - Info 1
      <button class="btn btn-light" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".cell-col-0" aria-expanded="false">Toggle</button>
    </th>
…
    <th>
      Step 1 - User+Date
      <button class="btn btn-light" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".cell-col-1" aria-expanded="false">Toggle</button>
    </th>
…
  </tr>
…
  <tr>
    <th><div class="cell-col-0">Step 0 - Info 1</div></th>
…
    <th><div class="cell-col-1">Step 1 - User+Date</div></th>
…
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="cell-col-0">Step 0 - Info 1 - Row 1</div></td>
…
    <td><div class="cell-col-1">Step 1 - User+Date - Row 1</div></td>
…
```

Comment: Thank you, sounds quite complicated, i am not sure if i really need such huge libraries for a single function. 
I found several code snippets over the web that do most of the wanted stuff, but here and then is something missing which makes me continue my search.
However i'll have to look further into those libraries in the future for upcoming stuff so your post is a good start

Comment: These are some quality criteria that I posted here, that apply to “code snippets” as well – which I called scripts. Before you copy & paste a code snippet, you need to take these criteria into account. For example, the code snippet in the other answer is not accessible, and the license obliges you to keep a link to the answer in your code, afaik. You decide for yourself what you care about, even if implicitly by ignoring these points. (:

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use an unwieldy library. Plain "Vanilla" JavaScript will do. The following lines of code will make a `col` within a `colgroup` disappear, when you deselect its corresponding checkbox on top of the table:

```js
/* // ===========================================================
// un-comment this section when you run this from your PHP server:

<?PHP $hidden = array(0,2); // hide steps 0 and 2 ?>
const hidden=<?PHP echo json_encode($hidden); ?>;

// ============================================================*/
// stackoverflow mockup of PHP input:
const hidden=[0,2];

const cols = document.querySelectorAll("table col:nth-child(n+4)"),
  ttls= [...document.querySelectorAll("table tr.ttl th:nth-child(n+4)")].map(t=>t.textContent),
  div = document.querySelector("div");
div.innerHTML=ttls.map(t=>`<label><input type="checkbox" checked>${t}</label>`).join(" ");
const cbs = div.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

hidden.forEach(h=>{cols[h].classList.add("hidden");cbs[h].checked=false});
cbs.forEach((cb,i)=>{
 cb.addEventListener("change",ev=>cols[i].classList.toggle("hidden",!cb.checked))
});

// enter a few lines of data into the table ... (to make it look more impressive)
document.getElementById("tbd").innerHTML = [...Array(5)].map((_, i) =>
  `<tr>${[...Array(25)].map((_,j)=>
    `<td>${(i+1)*100+j}</td>`).join("")}</tr>`).join("\n");
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid grey
}

.hidden {
  visibility: collapse
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <colgroup>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col span='11' class='step0'>
      <col span='2' class='step1'>
      <col span='3' class='step2'>
      <col span='3' class='step3'>
      <col span='3' class='step4'>
    </colgroup>
    <tr class="ttl">
      <th rowspan='2'>ID</th>
      <th rowspan='2'>Name</th>
      <th rowspan='2'>State</th>
      <th colspan='11'>Step 0</th>
      <th colspan='2'>Step 1</th>
      <th colspan='3'>Step 2</th>
      <th colspan='3'>Step 3</th>
      <th colspan='3'>Step 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Step 0 - Info 1</th>
      <th>Step 0 - Info 2</th>
      <th>Step 0 - Info 3</th>
      <th>Step 0 - Info 4</th>
      <th>Step 0 - Info 5</th>
      <th>Step 0 - Info 6</th>
      <th>Step 0 - Info 7</th>
      <th>Step 0 - Info 8</th>
      <th>Step 0 - Info 9</th>
      <th>Step 0 - User+Date</th>
      <th>Step 0 - Notes</th>
      <th>Step 1 - User+Date</th>
      <th>Step 1 - Notes</th>
      <th>Step 2 - Info</th>
      <th>Step 2 - User+Date</th>
      <th>Step 2 - Notes</th>
      <th>Step 3 - Info</th>
      <th>Step 3 - User+Date</th>
      <th>Step 3 - Notes</th>
      <th>Step 4 - Info</th>
      <th>Step 4 - User+Date</th>
      <th>Step 4 - Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbd"></tbody>
</table>
```

I am not sure whether this will work on *all* browsers, but I tested it successfully on Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

Comment: Thank you, running the snipped inside stackoverflow works fine, using it on a test file containing js, css and the table (of course in the right place - i hope at least) brings me up the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children')" in console.
What I miss (i guess i was not clear) is a way to show the steps again, so i'd need some kind of link to open them again.
And also i am not really clear what you mean with location.search? I found out that it makes the part after a ? available as variable but how to further use it?

Comment: I didn’t know about `display: collapse`, pretty cool!

Comment: I added some buttons to make hidden columns visible again.

Comment: And regarding @Andy comment that "the code [in my answer] is not accessible": **Yes, it is!** Everything here is open and clearly readable to everyone in the world. It is up to you to learn from it, and - after fully understanding and adapting it - to eventually make it _your own code_! Andy quite rightly mentioned a very important point though: never simply."cut &paste" code without understanding what you are doing!

Comment: I’m not sure if we’re on the same page concerning the meaning of accessibility. I’m talking about the usability of the interface by persons with disabilities. For example, the cells that function as the toggles are not focusable by keyboard, which is kind of a necessary baseline for accessibility. Then, probably some `aria-expanded` hints would be necessary to indicate what the buttons do, and that you actually can collapse a cell.

Comment: @Andy, Thanks for the explanation - yes - that is certainly a valid point. wherever it applies. I have to admit, that so far I have not really considered "accessibility" as a design aspect. My pages are mainly used as internal pages in our company.

Comment: Thanks for adding those buttons, will bring me forward.

On the other hand, it still does not work, i copied and pasted your code just for trying it, there's still the Javascript error.
 As written I need it for our intranet only so it does not have to be that accessible.

Comment: It does not even generate the test lines of your example (i kept that part in for trying).
I really do not understand why it does not work in a test file using exactly whats written in your post (of course inside the specific parts like <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">, <style> and a html file structure.
For a better looking solution, is it possible to "reduce" the hidden columngroup to just one columngroup containing the Heading of the colgroup and a + or - symbol to collapse/expand? 
Honestly I tought it would be easier to do, i have less clue of JS than i even tought

Comment: Put your `<script>` tag with my script in it _under_ the closing `</body>` tag of your HTML. That is the easiest way of making sure the DOM is loaded before the script starts. Your current errors are probably a result of trying to access DOM elements before they are there (i. e. before the HTML was fully parsed and processed).

Comment: That was it. I tought that scripts usually have to be in <head> area. But its some years ago when i've "learned" this.
Putting them below /body did the job. Thank you!

So do you have an idea about improving the useability like
"or a better looking solution, is it possible to "reduce" the hidden columngroup to just one narrow column containing the Heading of the colgroup and a + or - symbol to collapse/expand (or a similar way)?"

Comment: @CarstenMassmann Can you help me with that last thing? Would help me a lot

Comment: A minus symbol (==>button) would be easy to implement, but *the plus is not that straight forward*. Where would you put it? In the preceding or the next column header? And what happens, if that column is "collapsed" too? For that reason I created those numbered buttons on top of the table. Each one of these buttons becomes visible as soon as its associated column is collapsed.

Comment: You're right, thats why I asked about reducing the column groups to one column. But right, thats not that easy.

Comment: The column numbers would be a bit complicated to understand, could there be checkboxes instead with a label containing the name of the column groups (in the example Step1, Step2, etc.) or at least buttons with those names?

Comment: Well, yes, using checkboxes for the column selection sounds like a good idea! Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Got it working, awesome. Just changed the location of the checkboxes to <legend> for the moment as I wasnt able to make this work with a specific div class. Tried around with querySelector("div.legend") (for using a <div class="legend"></div>) but it did not work

Comment: However i have two wishes to make it perfect:
1) How can I make the first three columns (ID, Name, State) non-switchable, so they are always shown? I also tried changging querySelector ("table tr.ttl") to table th.ttl and adding class="ttl" to the specific th fields, but that did not work.

2) Biggest remaining wish would be to display or hiding a column-set ("step") depending on a php variable. The table is included in several different php pages a views so i could pre-define views by setting variables for them.

Thanks for your help, let me know how I can spend you some coffee :)

Comment: Right, this post has mutated into a "coding-on-demand-service". You are lucky I have plenty of time on my hands and I am in a good mood, but it would be a good idea if you yourself started experimenting a bit more! Have a look at my modified post. The php variable `$hidden` contains an array with hidden step numbers (here: `0` and `2`). These columns will be hidden right from the start (but - of course - can be un-hidden on demand again). You should of course use your own php code to generate the array in `$hidden`.

Comment: I know its a bit much asked and i am sorry about it, i understand your code but its a hard way to create some on my own but i was able to implement it in the real table and it works fine.
JS is for me like a closed book but meanwhile it opened a bit, i just was not sure how to close the gap from php variables to js.

Thanks a lot. Not only for the code itself, also for the examples I could learn from.

Comment: There's one more tought:
After I hide a column, the table width becomes smaller, can I somehow use always around 100%?
So there's a real advantage of hiding columns?

Comment: So in theory a solution could be applying a css class to the table with a width of 100% but i did not get it to work

Comment: Ich bekomms leider nicht selbst hin, ich habe eine neue CSS-Klasse "table100" angelegt mit dem Parameter width: 100%,
dann unter  cb.addEventListener("change",ev=>cols[i].classList.toggle("hidden",!cb.checked))

die Zeile

 cb.addEventListener("change",ev=>table[i].classList.toggle("table100",!cb.checked))

ergänzt.
Aber ja, ergibt irgendwie wenig Sinn an dieser Stelle, ich verstehe aber nicht, wo ich hinzufügen kann, dass die Tabelle nach jeder Änderung auf die 100% gesetzt wird.

Comment: Im Grunde sollte visibility: collapse das ja sowieso machen, ich vermute aber, dass dazu die Tabelle neu geladen werden müsste (?)

Comment: I did experiment with it for a while but could not get any satisfactory results. Maybe a complete reload is required after all ... you can contact me under carsten.massmann@gmail.com .